# How to conditionally remove a property from an object?

Tags: javascript

Write a function called "removeNumbersLargerThan".

Given a number and an object, "removeNumbersLargerThan" removes any properties whose values are numbers greater than the given number.

```
var obj = {
  a: 8,
  b: 2,
  c: 'montana'
}

removeNumbersLargerThan(5, obj);

console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2, c: 'montana' }
```

my code:

```
function removeNumbersLargerThan(num, obj) {
  // your code here
  if (obj[prop] < num) {
    delete obj[prop];
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my code? I'm not sure how to get rid of a property from an object if the property isn't defined?

Comment: I think you and [this poster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615295/iterative-conditional-removal-of-object-property-using-for-in-and-if) are using the same text book...

Comment: *Larger* than. You're doing less than. `<` should be `>`. And you need to iterate over the properties. Read up on `for...in` loops.

Comment: @Santi Ack! Good catch.

Comment: *"What's wrong with my code?"* The most obvious mistake is that `prop` is not defined anywhere. Where do you expect it to come from?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you're trying to remove numbers that are smaller than a given number. You can fix this by using `property > num` instead of `property < num`.

Next, you're not actually looking at all of the properties. Infact, prop is undefined. You need to use a `for` loop to check each property.

```js
var obj = {
  a: 8,
  b: 2,
  c: 'montana'
}

removeNumbersLargerThan(5, obj); console.log(obj); // --> { b: 2, c: 'montana' }

function removeNumbersLargerThan(num, obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj[property] > num) {
            delete obj[property];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shirley: be sure you credit Toby for the answer in your homework.  Academia doesn't usually take kindly to plagiarism without attribution.

Comment: @blex You're absolutely right, I've added the changes. Thanks!